# Why are there multiple sets of cookies under Resources -> Cookies in Chrome Dev-tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain, google-chrome-devtools

I have enclosed a screenshot of my devtools open (on resources tab) with our beloved stackoverflow.com as the example. Like many other sites, I often see cookies belonging to other domains for the domain I am visiting, as well as other domains listed by themselves underneath Cookies.

For example, underneath Cookies there is a section for stackoveflow.com and you will see cookies assigned to not only stackoverflow.com but other domains such as adzerk.net, quantserve.com, etc. This makes perfect sense to me.

But why are there additional sections for doubleverify and betrad? If they are cookies for other domains, why are they here and get sections all to themselves?

[image]

Why are these cookies just not all listed under the single domain I am currently visiting and why do some get appended to the main domain and some get their own subsection?

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse this site (like others) uses external content. For example, if you use an iframe to load content (like a facebook button), facebook stores their cookies from that iframe.

**edit**: As I commented below, if this answer is wrong: "Oh, then because the cookies were stored originally from stackoverflow's domain :)"

**re-edit** to clarify: If a website (for example stackoverflow) stores an external cookie, chrome dev-tools shows you, at first instance, into stackoverflow domain's name. The cookie is external, but stackoverflow is the causer of that. For that reason you see it there, into stackoverflow domain's name. But, as the cookie is not from stackoverflow, dev-tools have to think: "oh, this is a different domain, I have to create -also and anyway- a new domain name to store it".

Hope this helps you to understand the functionality of dev-tools panel

Comment: I think he knows this, and what he's asking is why when you click on "stackoverflow.com" on left, you get cookies from stackoverflow and other places like adzerk.net on the right, while stuff from doubleverify is still on the left.

Comment: Oh, then because the cookies were stored originally from stackoverflow's domain :)

Comment: could you edit your answer and elaborate on the cookies being stored originally from stackoverflow? that doesn't clear up the two different sets for me

Comment: edited to clarify much as possible. sorry if is not enough, but it has not more science